# Duplicating entries with associations in elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

My blog app has a feature that allows people to make copies of other people's posts, and host them as their own.

`Post`s are associated with owners.

```
  schema "posts" do 
    field :title, :string 
    field :content, :string 

    belongs_to :owner, MyApp.Accounts.User, foreign_key: :owner_id
  end
```

I would like to get a copy of a `Post` by id, remove the id and owner_id fields, cast the new owner id, and then insert.

```
resolve fn (%{post_id: post_id, new_owner_id: new_owner_id}, _info) ->
  Repo.get!(Post, post_id)
    |> Map.delete(:id)
    |> Map.delete(:owner_id)
    |> Post.changeset(%{owner_id: new_owner_id})
    |> Repo.insert!
end
```

But when I do, I get this error:

```
Request: POST /api
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (RuntimeError) attempting to cast or change association `owner` from `MyApp.Content.List` that was not loaded. Please preload your associations before manipulating them through changesets
```

What is the correct way to do this copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was clearly mentioned in the error message:

> Please preload your associations before manipulating them through changesets

```rb
resolve fn (%{post_id: post_id, new_owner_id: new_owner_id}, _info) ->
  Post
  |> Repo.preload(:owner) # ⇐ this
  |> Repo.get!(post_id)
  |> Map.delete(:id)
  |> Map.delete(:owner_id)
  |> Post.changeset(%{owner_id: new_owner_id})
  |> Repo.insert!
end
```

---

*Sidenote:* I believe, you are doing it wrong. The better design would be to reflect the possible future changes in the “cited” post. Instead of copying it’s content, I would rather introduce the new many-to-many relationship between users and posts, called e.g. “copies.”

**Copy by reference is better than copy by value.** [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is the one of very few that work *always*.

Comment: I should clarify: in this situation, forking/divergence of the data is desirable.  Changes to the newly copied post only exist on the new owner's copy of it.    Given those requirements, is this still the best way?

Comment: It heavily depends on what kind of changes we are talking about. If it’s about adding preface, comments, highlighting—then yes. If that’s about text correction, I doubt I appreciate plagiarism, and this is exactly what plagiarism is. So, I would definitely stick to having a reference to the original post and some “decoration” around, _clearly distinguished_. Maybe one might add some properties to this many-to-many table like “frozen” to prevent modifications according to original post (that implies storing versions of the posts,) or anything else, I dunno. Like that.

Comment: Anyway, for now you might just move on with `Repo.preload`, you’ll get back to thank me for the idea later :)

Comment: Done and done.  I'm using this for a different purpose actually, I just use the example of a Blog for all my SO examples.  Sometimes the metaphor doesn't extend very well :P